# Exporting crown boundaries from tree segmentation in R?

Tags: r, vector, export, lidar, lidr

I am using lidR package to segment my trees using `lastrees` directly from the points clouds.

The function works fine, however I would like to export to vector file the canopy boundaries from `tree_segmentation` that I did directly from my point cloud.

Is it possible to extract canopy boundaries from segmentation `lastrees` in order to analyze my results I got?

```
las = lastrees(lasn,li2012(R = 3, speed_up = 5))
plot(las, color = "treeID", colorPalette = col2)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want vectors defined by the points of each colour blob obtained when you do a plot like `plot(las$X, las$Y, col=las$treeID)`? Then you want to maybe look at the convex hull or the convex "alpha shape" defined by each group of points with the same treeID...

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by *export to vector file the canopy boundaries*? Please edit your question to clarify. Does [this document](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/Segment-individual-trees-and-compute-metrics) help you?

Comment: Looks like tree_hulls is what I was thinking of. That can be written to a shapefile or geopackage using `writeOGR` from the `rgdal` package.

Answer (score 5):

This example is directly from the [documentation](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/Segment-individual-trees-and-compute-metrics) @JRR provided. You can use `writeOGR()` from the [rgdal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/rgdal.pdf) package to write the convex hull polygons representing tree canopies to shapefile.

```
library(lidR)
library(rgdal)

las = readLAS("/path/to/your/points.las")
plot(las)
```

[image]

```
# Classify ground points
las = lasground(las, csf())
plot(las, color = "Classification")
```

[image]

```
# Normalize points
las = lasnormalize(las, tin())
plot(las)
```

[image]

```
# Calculate the canopy height model (CHM)
algo = pitfree(thresholds = c(0,10,20,30,40,50), subcircle = 0.2)
chm  = grid_canopy(las, 0.5, algo)
plot(chm, col = height.colors(50))
```

[image]

```
# Optionally smooth the CHM with a 3x3 pixel moving window with a median statistic
ker = matrix(1,3,3)
chm = focal(chm, w = ker, fun = median)
chm = focal(chm, w = ker, fun = median)

plot(chm, col = height.colors(50)) # check the image
```

[image]

```
algo = watershed(chm, th = 4)
las  = lastrees(las, algo)

# remove points that are not assigned to a tree
trees = lasfilter(las, !is.na(treeID))

plot(trees, color = "treeID", colorPalette = pastel.colors(100))
```

[image]

```
# Calculate tree metrics and convex hulls
metric = tree_metrics(las, .stdtreemetrics)
hulls  = tree_hulls(las)
hulls@data = dplyr::left_join(hulls@data, metric@data)

spplot(hulls, "Z")
```

[image]

```
# Write to shapefile
writeOGR(obj=hulls, dsn="/Users/aaron/Desktop/", layer="hulls", driver="ESRI Shapefile") # this is in equal area projection
```