# How to use lastrees on a catalog with a function requiring a CHM raster?

Tags: r, lidar, las, lidr, canopy-height-model

I'm still fairly new to using LiDAR data and R, so please let me know if this isn't clear.

I am using the lidR package to segment individual trees over a large landscape. I have been using the catalog function to process the data in reasonable chunks, and have created and saved the CHMs for each chunk.

What I can't figure out is how to use the lastrees function on the catalog and call the correct CHM to use with the algorithm. Is there a way to do this within the package, maybe using catalog apply (still haven't figured that out), or am I better off attacking it some other way?

If there is a way to process the CHMs to make this easier, I'm willing to try that as well!

Comment: Actually there is no built-in function (yet) to segment trees over large landscape in lidR because it is more complex to do than it might appear. Moreover your question is not related to point-cloud processing but more to raster processing and yet you will find almost no tool in lidR for that.

Comment: There is nothing impossible actually but you should first mention what kind of output you are expecting. Do you want a raster-based tree segmentation or a point-cloud-based segmentation? I guess the first one and consequently you should study how to process large raster with `raster` instead of large point cloud with `lidR`

Comment: @Andre Silva the difficulty come with the edge of the processed chunks. Processing the dataset into independent chunks implies that there is no easy wall-to-wall continuity. At the edge of a chunk you will have the first half of a tree labelled `123` and the second half of the same tree from another chunk will be labelled `456`. Wall-to-wall continuity is the reason why `lastrees` does not have a `LAscatalog` version yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to answer, let’s put aside important, but broad issues:

- The fact that identifying and segmenting trees is a very complex analysis which depends on many things (things related to the type of vegetation, and quality and amount of available data, for example).
- That processing 'large point clouds' in R is a real concern (due to memory limitation), and still depends on how large the study area is, how large the point cloud is; the goal of the analysis; if the point cloud can be preliminarily thinned, filtered, spatially sampled; the hardware; etc.
- That the question is not entirely clear; if working with a catalog and using CHMs are mandatory; the context of the analysis; type of output; reproducible code, etc.

Regarding using `lastrees` with a catalog, as [explained](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323506/how-do-i-use-lastrees-on-a-catalog-with-a-function-requiring-a-chm-raster#comment527902_323506) by JRR, it is not currently possible (version 2.0.3):

> the difficulty come with the edge of the processed chunks. Processing the dataset into independent chunks implies that there is no easy wall-to-wall continuity. At the edge of a chunk you will have the first half of a tree labelled 123 and the second half of the same tree from another chunk will be labelled 456. Wall-to-wall continuity is the reason why lastrees does not have a LAscatalog version yet.

Using a CHM with `lastrees` is possible as long as one chooses a segmentation algorithm which takes it as an argument. For example, `silva2016` (not me), `dalponte2016`, `watershed`, etc. The following is a well crafted answer about this: [Exporting crown boundaries from tree segmentation in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312230/exporting-crown-boundaries-from-tree-segmentation-in-r/312312#312312). Also, carefully read the package's documentation. It will explain that such algorithms can be run independent of the point cloud; i.e., at most, the LiDAR data can be used to register the results from the CHM-based segmentation.

And since this is a subject which still is in the academic frontier, to deepen exploring other possibilities, the scientific literature is our friend. For example, see the articles recommended in [Extracting tree crown areas from remote sensing data (visual images and LiDAR)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124224/extracting-tree-crown-areas-from-remote-sensing-data-visual-images-and-lidar/124370#124370).

Comment: Thank you very much, there was a lot I was unfamiliar with and this has cleared things up- the lack of clarity with the question was certainly due to my fundamental misunderstandings of the process with the edges. Thank you!