# lidR: no slot of name "header" for this object of class "LAScatalog"

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

*edit:* This question does share an answer with [an existing question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323506/how-to-use-lastrees-on-a-catalog-with-a-function-requiring-a-chm-raster), and the problem is the same: lastrees() does not work on LAScatalogs. However, I'm going to leave this question up, because I think the code and error message makes it easier to find.

I'm using lidR 2.0.3 (from the rocker/geospatial image). I would like to perform tree segmentation on an entire LAScatalog using the Li 2012 algorithm:

```r
#### setup #####################################################################

# load packages
library(here)
library(lidR)

# load normalized point cloud catalog (just a pointer to the tiled point 
# clouds)
normalized_als = 
  readRDS(here::here('02-data',
                   'lidar',
                   'aerial',
                   'normalized_als_catalog.rds'))



#### configure catalog #########################################################
# set catalog output path 
lidR::opt_output_files(normalized_als) = 
  here::here('02-data',
             'lidar',
             'aerial',
             '02-segmented',
             '{ID}_segmented')

# don't use any points with Z below 0 when making the CHM
lidR::opt_filter(normalized_als) = 
  paste0(lidR::opt_filter(normalized_als), ', drop_z_below 0')

# use n-2 cores to process
lidR::opt_cores(normalized_als) = as.integer(parallel::detectCores()-2L)

# use a 20m buffer
lidR::opt_chunk_buffer(normalized_als) = 20

# process by files - this may preserve the lasheader?
lidR::opt_chunk_size(normalized_als) = 0

# run the algorithm, writing the segmented point cloud to disc
segmented_als = 
  lidR::lastrees(normalized_als,
               algorithm = li2012())
```

The last call to lastrees returns:

```
Error in algorithm(las):
    no slot of name "header" for this object of class "LAScatalog"
```

I've confirmed that the individual las files DO have valid headers, but it seems that lidR::li2012() is assuming that "las" is a LAS object, not a LAScatalog. The call fails at line 219 of lidR/R/algorithm-its.R:

```r
 if (las@header@PHB$`Max Z` < hmin)
```

**My question is: Is my code incorrect, or is this a bug in lidR::li2012()?** I'm trying to follow the examples on [the wiki](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-LAScatalog-class.html), but I don't 100% understand how lidR maps LAS-based functions over LAScatalogs, and it's very possible that I am misusing the lastrees function. (Is there some catalog_apply() approach that I should be using?) The li2012() function seems to expect a LAS object specifically, not a LAScatalog (which doesn't have a comparable header slot). How can I pass an actual LAS object to li2012()? I would just iterate over the separate tiles, but would like to use the buffering functionality offered by LAScatalogs. Alternatively, was the data validation checking for li2012() written with a LAS object in mind, and causing it to break when given a LAScatalog or a LAScluster?

I would be happy to email a reproducible dataset, but I believe the issue should be reproducible with an arbitrary catalog: Either my code is written incorrectly, or li2012() can't currently be used on LAScatalogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of `lastrees()` states:

> las An object of class LAS.

`lastrees()` does not support `LAScatalog` inputs. You may found more details [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323506/how-to-use-lastrees-on-a-catalog-with-a-function-requiring-a-chm-raster). The reason why `lastrees()` does not support catalog wide processing is currently the following:

> the difficulty come with the edge of the processed chunks. Processing the dataset into independent chunks implies that there is no easy wall-to-wall continuity. At the edge of a chunk you will have the first half of a tree labelled 123 and the second half of the same tree from another chunk will be labelled 456. Wall-to-wall continuity is the reason why `lastrees()` does not have a LAscatalog version yet.

This may change in future releases of the package for now you can't compute `lastrees()` on a `LAScatalog`. At least not with built-in function.

Comment: Thanks JRR! For anyone reading this in the future: As a workaround, I was able to clip the catalog by the different AOI polygons, writing a new LAS file for each. Then you can run lastrees separately on each AOI LASfile.