# Error in "writeOGR" When creating a shapefile from convex hulls

Tags: r, export, lidar, lidr

I am working on the segmentation of crown canopy  using LiDAR. I want to extract the crowns created after the segmentation as a shapefile. Other documentation and links show that using writeOGR I can create the shapefile from the crown canopy, but I get an error that:

> inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE

[Exporting crown boundaries from tree segmentation in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312230/exporting-crown-boundaries-from-tree-segmentation-in-r/312312#312312)

The code:

```
crowns <- crown_metrics(las, func = .stdtreemetrics, geom = "convex")
writeOGR(crowns, "building.shp", layer="convex", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `lidR 4.0.0` spatial objects returned by the package are in `sf` format. It no longer uses `sp`. The question you linked is old and lidR modernized the workflow one year ago. `writeOGR` was used in the good old time to write `Spatial*` object from `sp`. Modern spatial data in R now uses `sf`. You must use `st_write` from `sf`.